# PHP MySQL search character coding issues

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm using PDO to connect to a MySQL database. In my connection string I have already added `charset=utf8mb4` and all of my databases and tables are `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, But I'm facing a problem.

In order to search for entries based on their title on `content` table I'm using the code below:

`SELECT * FROM content WHERE title LIKE '%سيگنالها%'`

the keyword is a Persian word. Now the above code returns 1 result which is correct and as expected.

**But** If I make a form in my PHP app and enter the **SAME** word either by using a macOS/Windows PC or by using an Android phone I get 0 results.

I tracked this issue down and it seems like even though the words entered by user look exactly the same as the one already in the database, they are in fact **NOT** the same.

According to this [online tool](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html), the decimal character code

for `سيگنالها` it's: 1587, 1**61**0, 1711, 1606, 1575, 1604, 1607, 1575

While

for `سیگنالها` it's: 1587, 1**74**0, 1711, 1606, 1575, 1604, 1607, 1575

Did you spot the difference? It's in bold. In fact if you copy both values and past them in [here](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html) you will see the difference for yourself.

What can I do to solve this annoying problem? I'm using PHP 7 and MariaDB 10.1.

Comment: what is the page charset? it must be utf-8 and also, you must execute `SET NAMES utf8` after mysql connection. please post sample code.

Comment: @Akam It is `utf-8` also the above can be tested in phpmyadmin. Same results.

Comment: Ok then, this is keyboard issue, I am also using Unikurd (kurdish sorani) same letters as Persian and Arabic, sometimes, a user using a keyboard that has different Unicode entities than the one saved in the database, but we solved this issue by replacing the letters with common.

Comment: @Akam, How can I replace them with the common characters? What are common characters?

Comment: The common characters are those that commonly used by users, it depends on the keyboard layout that used by more users, the first y is "ي" while your second y is "ی" which are very different in their Unicode values, replace one of them by the common y.

Comment: This could be a collation problem where the database isn't able to determine which characters or character combinations are equivalent.

Comment: @Akam, You are right, If you could write this as an answer, I could accept it. The problem was in fact `ي` which was saved in the database while it should have been `ی`

Comment: Is there a linguistic or other distinction between the two YEHs?  They seem to collate differently, even with utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci.  (That is, Unicode 5.20 claims they should be treated as different characters.)

Comment: @RickJames No difference. One is used in Arabic while the other one is used exclusively in Persian. Usually they are pretty obvious and not hard to distinct but in this context they are located in the middle of the word and connected to other characters which makes it impossible to notice the difference just by looking at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first "ي" in the word "سيگنالها" is different character from second word "سیگنالها" which is "ی"

First ي: is ARABIC LETTER YEH (`U+064A`)

Second ی: is ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH (`U+06CC`)

They are different in their Unicode entities, so that they are not match.
Please see https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%EF%BA%95%EF%BA%8F%D8%A2-arabic-alphabet/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same character, even though they look the same when stringed together and might even have the same meaning.

The first string (1610) is ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH[1] while the other (1740) is ARABIC LETTER YEH[2].

[1] https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DB%8C
[2] https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%8A

I also created a simple form for PHP and tested both strings to see if the value sent through $_POST is kept. Result: the value isn't converted.

So what's probably going on is that you're using an Arabic keyboard to produce Farsi text. The recommended solution is some kind of normalization of the input.

See these discussions:

1) https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/persian-computing#!topic/persian-computing/xS-G0qIGS8A

2) https://github.com/Samsung/KnowledgeSharingPlatform/blob/master/sameas/lib/lucene-analyzers-common-5.0.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/fa/PersianNormalizer.java

3) [can't search in farsi text with arabic keyboard on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261258/cant-search-in-farsi-text-with-arabic-keyboard-on-iphone)